# Thai basic day time-units

Tags: thai

To ease my learning of Thai basic day time-units I have made the following chart consisting of these parts:

- Hour number in global enumeration
- Hour name in Thai
- General times of day for hour
- Specific times of day for hour

I understand there are four *specific times of day* that I described as I recognized from my teacher and wrote in English but I don't know how to write in Thai:

- Du**g
- Muu^t
- Saa∨y
- Kwa^m

Here are screenshots from the file I have made, which is lacking *specific times of day* in Thai script:

[image]

[image]

In Google translate and some other webpages about Thai basic day time-units I didn't find these *specific times of day* (at least transliterated in Thai script).

**How are these four *specific times of day* are written in Thai?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words in question seem to be (in order of appearance):

- [ดึก](http://www.thai-language.com/id/140330) `[dɯ̀k]` — *late at night*;
- [มืด](http://www.thai-language.com/id/133624#def2) `[mɯ̂ːt]` — *dark*; never heard of it used to tell time of day;
- [สาย](http://www.thai-language.com/id/131667#def7) `[sǎːj]` — *late*; as in "to be late"; again, never heard of it used to tell time of day; you've probably heard it in phrases like "to wake up late";
- "Kwa^m" seems to be actually [ค่ำคืน](http://www.thai-language.com/id/133263) `[kʰâm kʰɯːn]` — *dusk, sunset time*.

In addition, it is normally to say ตอน[คืน](http://www.thai-language.com/id/131448) `[tɔːn kʰɯːn]` to colloquially tell the period of time between midnight and 6AM.

See also Wikipedia page for [Thai six-hour clock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_six-hour_clock) for more colloquial words you may find interesting.

---

P.S. Because the question is about specific words in a language, it is not about linguistics (as a scientific study of languages in general) at all, so I'm afraid it will be closed soon.

P.P.S. There have been several attempts to create a language-specific site for Thai language on [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) (including two or three mine), but all failed due to lack of interested users. If you feel interest and courage, please consider proposing a new site for Thai language and invite prominent users who would commit to it.

Comment: Hello; I feel I should also personally thank you for your answer which I find ordinal, flow, clear and nice to read, hence didactic.

Comment: bytebuster; I never used Area51 and not sure I have the free time and interest to join that community - but between us I ask you; why not creating a "South east Asian" languages stackexchange about Khmer, Thai, Lao, Vietnamese and (the quite different from all of these) Burmese?

Comment: @JohnDoea, because it will be closed due to "vague topic". Think of it: there are no professionals in "Southeast Asian Languages". One of my proposals was for "Thai and Lao Languages", but it was an experiment; failed, too. It's like proposing a site like "All Natural Languages". ;)

Comment: bybuster, I personally think the comparison between a possible south east Asian languages SE to all natural languages SE is not correct but I can agree to the notion that southeast Asian language SE (at least as I firstly suggested) might be too broad: I would personally suggest to include Khmer in Thai-Lao project due to what I described in the following link (especially in **Comparison 2: Khmer words**) and more thins I didn't present there: https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34524/modern-khmer-and-modern-vietnamese-genetic-proximity/34528?noredirect=1#comment75759_34528

Comment: @JohnDoea, the bottom line is: you can try proposing, sharing your vision, convincing other users and SE staff for your proposal in your redaction. If you expend enough effort you can possibly win. But the more different your proposal is from "standards" the bigger the criticism you should expect and theharder it would be to convince others.

Comment: bytebuster, I find this likely in regards to SE; I might suggest a similar project; I strongly hold the belief that this life is very much a struggle and some unorthodox ideas deserved to at least be preserved, even if rejected.

Comment: Hi, I just searched for "Thai language" proposal in Area 51 to write there that I agree and support and, but din't find it. Was it deleted ? Google search didn't help also. Is there a link? Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JohnDoea, inactive proposals get deleted. You can't just "write that you support it". :) Area 51 work in a different way; there must be a substantial number of users who "follow" the proposal, write sample questions and vote for them, then on 2nd stage they "commit" to it, then they support the Beta site with their active participation. At every stage there's a threshold of minimal activity, and the proposal gets closed if it does not match the threshold.